# Angular 4 and bootstrap - Adding container class to component selector

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, components

I am currently adding bootstrap's container class to the component selector so all child elements react to bootsrap classes

for example in the index.html file i've applied

```
<app-root class="container"></app-root>
```

and in the bootstrapped app.component.html I've applied

```
<app-header class="row"></app-header>
```

Not sure if this is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend in app.component put the container class

```
<div class="container">

       <app-header></app-header>

</div>
```

and in the component app-header.component

```
<div class="row">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i am using angular4 Jquery plugin to add custom classes to components on creation with
`jQuery('app-header').addClass('class1 class2 class3')`

maybe you can use something like this in ngOnInit() or where it fits you best

Ex:

> ```
>    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
>     @Component({
>       selector: 'app-header',
>       templateUrl: './app-component.html',
>       styleUrls: ['./app-component.css']
>     })
>     export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
>       ngOnInit(): void {
>         jQuery('app-header').addClass('col-sm-6 example-class');
>       }
>     }
> ```

Then it should look something like this:
`<app-header class="col-sm-6 example-class">`
...

I do not know if this is the right way but it works for me for now

I hope it helps, Cheers

Comment: Unless there is a need to programmatically add a class to the 'app-root' as you've demonstrated in ngOnInit would it not be simpler and convenient to add the classes ''col-sm-6 example-class' to the 'app-root' selector directly?

Comment: i am using it like this for dynamically loaded components, i did not find another way for doing this so bootstrap will recognize cards added as angular modules for example(p.s.: i am using app-root selector in the example just to fit his case better)